# Python: access list value by reference

Tags: python, list, syntax

Very basic question here (I've just started with Python).

I have a list object. It contains five numbers [3,6,2,3,1]

I want find the sum of the first, third and fourth numbers in the list.

What is the syntax?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can for instance sum elements #1, #3, and #4 with the flexible expression

```
sum(my_list[i] for i in (0, 2, 3))
```

The index of the first element is 0 [not 1], etc., i.e. `my_list[0]` is the first element (with value 3, in the original question), etc.

Answer (score 6):

The items of a list are numbered like this:

```
   a = [3, 6, 2, 3, 1]
        ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
index   0  1  2  3  4
```

To access the item with the index `i`, use `a[i]`.  From here, you should be able to figure out how to sum the desired items.

Answer (score 3):

Just write the index in brackets. Note that the index starts with zero:

```
lst[0] + lst[2] + lst[3]
```

In some cases, you can use the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function and select a [slice](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) of the list. For example, to get the sum of the first, third, and fifth element, use:

```
sum(lst[::2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access an element of a Python list by index by appending `[list_index]` to the list object (replace `list_index` with the index you want).  For example:

```
my_list_object = [3,6,2,3,1]
my_sum = my_list_object[0]+my_list_object[2]+my_list_object[3]
```